# Filters (Parameters) for RDL (Paginated) report in PowerBI-JavaScript API

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-js-api

Looks like filters (parameters) are not applied and not fetched for Paginated Reports similar to Sample Reports as shown in demo (https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html#)

```
report.setFilters([filter]); 
report.getFilters();
```

**Is there any way to fetch filters and apply them for embedded Paginated reports?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power BI embedded JS SDK doesn't support get / set filters on Paginated reports.

In [Power BI Embedded Playgroud](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html#):
go to Sample Tool ->  Sample Paginated Report ->  hit "Run" on the code section to embed a sample paginated report -> navigate to "Interact" tab to see all the supported APIs for paginated reports